# Populating a textbox, if another textbox is populated

Tags: vb.net

i've got two textboxes in my form.

According to title, when I write something in one textbox (a random one), i need that at the same time, in the other textbox a text (given in the code) appears. 
1 letter for 1 letter

1)Example with random text:

1 textbox ) How are you?
2 textbox)  Let's just c

2)Example with random text:

1 textbox ) What is the aim of the project?
2 textbox)  Let's just chill out for a mome

thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to determine which responses you would like to which questions. However, the tackle to letter for letter problem. I would use the substring method and get the length of the current text.

```
 Dim Response as String = "Hello World!"
 Private Sub Text(ByVal..) Handles Textbox1.changed
 Textbox2.text = Response.Substring(0, Textbox1.text.length)

 End Sub
```

As the text changes in the textbox you are typing in, this will output the response corresponding to the length of the text input. Since the event is textbox.changed, each character entered will update the second textbox

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an event based code here. I would use a loop per stroke of the key and make the event "Key Press." Write the code onto the textbox you are inserting data into.

Comment: Could you be more detailed Sir?